# navigation between views in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to make my first app in Xcode. This tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgd6mCuzlEc helped me understand how to make navigation between views. In my app I need more buttons on first and second view but buttons on second view are dependet on buttons from first view.

For example buttons on first view:
- birds
- dogs
- fishes

second view for birds:
- stork
- sparrow
- chicken

On a third view will be describtion for chosen animal.

What should be my next step? Example from link is good for my app?

Comment: add buttons as subview on secondView by generating through code not using xib.If using xib then need to hide show Or add or remove as subview to secondView.Need to add button on the basis of your choice in first view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is create a public (in the .h file) variable in the second view. lets say this variable will be NSString:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *caseStr;
```

now dont forget to create an initialiser in your second view .m file

```
@synthesize caseStr = _caseStr;

-(void)setCaseStr:(NSString *)caseStr
{
    _caseStr = caseStr;
}
```

now on your first view implement the "prepareForSegue" method:
(we assume that your segue identifier is "ChosenAnimal" and type of bird is a local string that set to be "Birds","Dogs" or "Fish"

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ChosenAnimal"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setCaseStr:typeOfBird];
    }
}
```

now you have the info of what been selected in the first view and you can do with it whatever you want in the second view.

BTW: if you would ever like to control the first view from the second view you will have to use delegate. good luck

Answer (score 1):

You could declare your initializer for your second view controller to take data. When you initialize that view controller from your first view controller, just be sure to pass the data. Then you could set the button text in your `viewDidLoad:` method on your second view controller (You could try doing this in your `initWithData` method but sometimes xib elements aren't properly initialized at that point)